# Do not see Images

Tags: us20150309854

In reference to the patent: [US20150309854](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150309854)

I want to know why do not see the images?

Answer (score 1):

The images are available in [PDF form here on The Lens](https://www.lens.org/images/patent/US/20150309854/A1/US_2015_0309854_A1.pdf).  An open, persistent and public resource with no click-tracking, advertising or other privacy invasion.

Comment: The Lens is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You're not crazy (In case that's what you were thinking).

The images don't show on that patent link for me either, neither does the PDF.

When I view it from this URL, I am able to see the full patent with images (via the PDF link on this site):

http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2015/0309854.html

Answer (score 0):

Many a times Google patents doesn't show the patent PDF. There are other websites where you can do this freely though. I have often found that http://www.pat2pdf.org is the best. Even though there are free sites like - http://www.patentretriever.com/ or http://www.freepatentpdfs.com/

Answer (score 0):

People often make the mistake of searching for patents from the base www.google.com site. It works much better to search from patents.google.com. For instance here is the same [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150309854A1/en) which includes the figures.